# Line Chart in Windows Store App

Tags: c#

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<FinancialStuff> financialStuffList = new List<FinancialStuff>();
financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "MSFT", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "AAPL", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "GOOG", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "BBRY", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });

(LineChart.Series[0] as LineSeries).ItemsSource = financialStuffList;
```

I want to pass empty `key(Name)` and its value may be different.
i donot want to display name but want to display its associated value..is it possible in Windows store app?